# Expo SecureStore is clear after re-login or when restarting the app

Tags: react-native, expo, storage

I am using `expo-secure-store@12.1.1` to keep refId in expo react native app.
Here is a codesnipet:

```
export const selectRefID = (refId) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        const value = "" + refId;
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync("select_ref_id", value);
      } catch (e) {
        Sentry.Native.captureException(e);
      }
    }, 1);
  };
};
```

And I am getting `select_ref_id` when app is loading.

```
export const loadProfile = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    ...
    try {
        selectedRefId = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("select_ref_id");
        if (selectedRefId) {
          selectedRefId = Number(selectedRefId);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        Sentry.Native.captureException(e);
    }
    ...
  };
};
```

But I am getting `NULL` when I try to logout and login again, and I turn off the app and turn on it again.

Thanks for your help in advance.